# How can I display a manual efficiently in Sharepoint

Tags: database, sharepoint, intranet

My organisiation uses Sharepoint for its 'intranet'. I have been given the task of creating a site for my department. One of the things I need on there is a procedure guide, which is basically a 150 page document, whereby each page is a separate procedure. Is there an efficient way within sharepoint that these procedures can be stored and searchable somehow, rather than dumping a 150 page document on there?

Answer (score 0):

Create and maintain this guide in either .doc(x) or .pdf format.

Place it in a Document Library and enable search and indexing on your site. (If you choose the PDF format, you will have to additionally install the PDF iFilters on the server).
The document will be searchable this way, this is basic SharePoint functionality, so there is no need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be worth looking into using the wiki piece of SharePoint.  We have effectively used it for some administration guides and such.